# git sync specific folders in two remote repositories

Tags: git, polling

I have two different repositories with a same folder (bin, very less push expected). Is it possible to do something like this if I push anything in that specific folder it will publish the same change in second repository. 
I know I can do it using jenking to poll on repository but polling can't be configured on a specific folder. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is adding the other machine repo as Remote using `git remote add` [command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html) and when ever you are pushing the changes, make sure you push to the other remote repository too. Better write a shell script which does this, so you will not forget it to sync.

One more way is use sync softwares like Dropbox, or [Sync](https://www.getsync.com/). I prefer the second one, which does the job.